# Listing all cubic order derivatives of a function of 4 variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

What would be the best way to list/print all cubic order derivatives of a function of 4 variables? I was thinking about iterating `Derivative[i,j,k,l][func][0,0,0,0]` for some $i,j,k,l\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ such that $|i+j+k+l|=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example for `f[___]= Sin[ x y z w]`

```
l = Flatten[ Permutations /@ (PadRight[#, 4] & /@ IntegerPartitions[3]), 1]
(Derivative[##][f][x, y, z, w] & @@@ l) /. f -> (Sin[#1 #2 #3 #4] &)
```

Comment: Why the replacement?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It seems to me the easier way to exemplify its usage.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following way. 
This:

```
 lst = Select[
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, l}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 3}, {l, 0, 
     3}], 3], Abs[Total[#]] == 3 &]

(* {{0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
  2}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 3, 
  0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 
  1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 
  0}, {3, 0, 0, 0}}  *)
```

makes the list of orders, and this

```
  (D[f[x, y, z, 
      t], {x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}, {z, #[[3]]}, {t, #[[4]]}] & /@ 
   lst) /. (# -> 0 &) /@ {x, y, z, t}
```

returns the list of the derivatives in question. Try it.

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

(1) Replace each variable by itself times a new variable (same new variable for all replacements).

(2) Take nth derivative with respect to the new variable.

(3) Set value of new variable to 1.

I illustrate with `n=2` and three variables.

```
vars = {x, y, z};
D[(f @@ vars) /. Thread[vars -> t*vars], {t, 2}] /. t -> 1

(* z*(z*Derivative[0, 0, 2][f][x, y, z] + 
    y*Derivative[0, 1, 1][f][x, y, z] + 
        x*Derivative[1, 0, 1][f][x, y, z]) + 
   y*(z*Derivative[0, 1, 1][f][x, y, z] + 
        y*Derivative[0, 2, 0][f][x, y, z] + 
        x*Derivative[1, 1, 0][f][x, y, z]) + 
   x*(z*Derivative[1, 0, 1][f][x, y, z] + 
        y*Derivative[1, 1, 0][f][x, y, z] + 
    x*Derivative[2, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]) *)
```

Comment: @belisarius I thought it was kind of cuke myself. Actally I learned it from MathGroup back in the 90's. I believe the first to come out with this approach was Andre Deprit, in the context of multivariate series.